# Input ran out of Data error but the data is there

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Good day, Trying to learn CNN and ran into an issue while running the code below.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot

%matplotlib inline

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu')
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r'C:\Users\Raj Mulati\Downloads\Dev\Machine Learning A-Z New\Part 8 - Deep Learning\Section 40 - 
Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)\dataset\training_set',

    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        r'C:\\Users\Raj Mulati\\Downloads\\Dev\\Machine Learning A-Z New\Part 8 - Deep 
Learning\\Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN)\\dataset\\test_set',

    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    training_set,
    steps_per_epoch=8000,
    epochs=25,
    validation_data=test_set,
    validation_steps=2000
 )
```

The error I got was:

```
Found 8000 images belonging to 2 classes.

Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
Train for 8000 steps, validate for 2000 steps
Epoch 1/25
 250/8000 [..............................] - ETA: 14:37 - loss: 0.2485 - accuracy: 0.5340WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 200000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x234d9fec3c8>
```

Comment: Where's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One step takes a complete batch of images, i.e. if your `batch_size` is 32, you run out of data after 250 steps (250 * 32 = 8000). Set your `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` like this:

```
model.fit_generator(
    training_set,
    steps_per_epoch=8000//32,
    epochs=25,
    validation_data=test_set,
    validation_steps=2000//32
 )
```